# jQuery autofill with multiple values and icons (email to field)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, email-client

I want to create a recipient field on a form using a jQuery autocomplete field for the lookup. I want this to be allowing multiple values.  I am already clued up on how to do this.

The catch is, when adding a recipient and using auto complete to perform the lookup, the recipient name should have a **blue background with a remove icon (x)** next to it, similar to the "To" field on the iPhone, or the person lookup in Facebook (when creating a new group in FB for instance)

Any ideas welcome!

Thanks for your time,
Albert

Comment: Rather than expecting someone to provide code for you, perhaps you could show what you've got so far and describe the modifications you want.  Even better, put up a live demo at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Totally agree with rchem, that's why I'm pointing you to the correct direction :) cheers!

Comment: Was just asking if there is already such a plugin or provide ideas. Not asking you guys to write it...

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to understand that what you want to do is not a function available by default with just one html element (in this case an input).

I won't enter in many technical details since that would mean spoon-feeding, I prefer to point you into the right direction; hope you don't mind, here it goes:

Firs you need to have a container that will look like a block, lets say a div. Inside of it you'll have the input field which should take just a part of the container, like this:

```
<div id="tag_editor">
  <span id="tokens"><!-- js stores tags here --></span>
  <input type="text" id="tag_editor_input">
</div>
```

[image: container]

Once you write some text on that input, the autocompletion should appear normally. However, you'll need a hook so that when you're unfocused or click the suggestions your the content of the input gets converted to a HTML element displaying the data, you should stored in the tokens container.

Of course the input box will be the same, but it'll shift to the right, example:

[image]

Once you've done this, you should be able to add as many tags as needed. Then when you need to get the data, just iterate through the contents of `#tokens` and use them as a part of the data.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the input! I will definitely consider this method.  Will see if anyone else comes along with ideas/existing plug ins.